# Keystroke aggregation for live-search phrases

Tags: ruby, record, n-gram, edit-distance, record-linkage

As a result of a live-search on the website, I have a set of strings like:

```rb
[
  'how',
  'how do i',
  'how do i cancel my',
  'how do i cancel my account',
  'where is',
  'where is the',
  'where is the analytics',
  'where is the analytics page'
]
```

I need to apply an edit distance algorithm that will leave me with just the two “final” phrases:

```rb
[
  'how do i cancel my account',
  'where is the analytics page'
]
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions on the implementation.

UPD: This is going to be used for search analytics, so potentially tens of thousands of records to be processed.

UPD2: I've ended up with this approach, which gives me a steady `>0.8` score to filter the final queries. I'm curious to hear about alternatives. The [Jaro-Winkler similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance#Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_Similarity) algorithm seems the most fitting, because it gives more priority to the leading characters over the trailing.

```rb
require 'edits'

values = [
  'how',
  'how do i',
  'how do i cancel my',
  'how do i cancel my account',
  'where is',
  'where is the',
  'where is the analytics',
  'where is the analytics page'
]

values.map(&:strip).uniq
  .each_cons(2)
  .map do |seq|
    [
      seq.first,
      seq.last,
      Edits::JaroWinkler.similarity(seq.first, seq.last)
    ]
  end
```

```rb
["how", "how do i", 0.8541666666666666]
["how do i", "how do i cancel my", 0.888888888888889]
["how do i cancel my", "how do i cancel my account", 0.9384615384615385]
["how do i cancel my account", "where is", 0.47243589743589737]
["where is", "where is the", 0.9333333333333333]
["where is the", "where is the analytics", 0.9090909090909091]
["where is the analytics", "where is the analytics page", 0.962962962962963]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should remove the prefixes.

```rb
require 'set'

suggestions = Set.new([
  'how',
  'how do i',
  'how do i cancel my',
  'how do i cancel my account',
  'where is',
  'where is the',
  'where is the analytics',
  'where is the analytics page'
])
phrases = suggestions.each do |a|
  suggestions.delete_if {|b| a != b && a.start_with?(b) }
end

phrases.to_a
```

Note that the above code is not performant for large arrays. But I imagine you wouldn't get more than 15 or 20 suggestions (with prefixes) from your app.

Reference: [Set#delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-delete_if)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is going to be used for search analytics, so potentially tens of thousands of records to be processed, which an array filtering approach wouldn't handle performantly.

Comment: @Adam Ah, I just saw your question edit about the input size. Let me see if I can come up with a better-performing algorithm.